# Questions with SQL - separating a column in two

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't know how I can answer this question. Because the name and last name are in one column. I'm not allowed to change the columns.

"Get the average spending (per customer) of all customers who share a last name with another customer"

I thought to say in sqlite3

```
SELECT avg_spending 
FROM customer 
JOIN customer on WHERE name is name;
```

This is how the table is defined:

```
CREATE TABLE customer 
(
    cuid INTEGER,
    name STRING,
    age INTEGER,
    avg_spending REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(cuid)
);
```

So those values are having the same last name

```
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (4, "Henk Krom", 65, 24);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (9, "Bob Krom", 66, 4);
```

Comment: As i can see there is only a column `name`.

Comment: Are the names in some standardized format? For instance always 'lastname, prename'. If not I don't see how to solve this in a reliable way ... If yes there is the `instr` and `substr` in sqlite which can be used to find a separator and get a substring from the name

Comment: yes there is only one column with name, i can't change the format

Comment: SELECT avg_spending FROM customer JOIN customer ON WHERE name LIKE name;
i thought something like this

Comment: Writing a query starts with the algorithm. So, state the rule how to extract the surname from the name. Look at derpirscher's question. Are the names in a reliable format? Can there be "John Smith", "Smith, John", "Smith John", "John R. Smith", "JOHN SMITH", "John Smith Snr.", …? Can you give a 100% rule how to extract the surname from the name?

Comment: I don't know how  i'm really stuck with the question

Comment: I think i need to join the customer table together and then i need to check the customers one by one what there last name is,

Comment: You can only write a query, when you know *what* to query. If there can be "John Smith" and "Smith John", how can you determine whcih is the first name and which is the surname? If the names are always first name - blank - surname, fine. If they are not, this may not even be completely feasable.

Comment: And names can be difficult. "Dostoevski", "Dostoevsky", "Dostoevsky", "Dostoevsky.", "Dostoiévski", "Dostojevski", "Dostojewski", "Dostojewskij", "Dostojewsky", "Dostoyevski", "Dostoyevsky", "Dostoyevsky", "Dostoyevsky", and "Dostoyevsky" are all the same name translated somehow from the cyrillic. The German name "Müller" can be spelled "MUELLER" in German, but would rather be "MULLER" in an American list.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner comparing names can lead to errors because there can be duplicates which refer to different persons.

Comment: @Marios Nikolaou: This is what this is all about. Find customers where *another* customer has the same last name.

Comment: I didn't notice it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I really appreciate this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the crux of this is to find a rule how to reliably extract the surname from the name. Apart from that you merely need an exists clause, because you want to select customers where another customer with the same surname exists.

("Get the average spending (per customer)" simply means get a row from the table, because each row contains exactly one customer and their average spending.)

If all names were in the format `first name - blank - last name`, that would be:

```
select * 
from customer c
where exists
(
  select *
  from customer other
  where other.cuid <> c.cuid
  and substr(other.name, instr(other.name, ' ') + 1) = substr(c.name, instr(c.name, ' ') + 1)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the sample data you posted I guess the format of the column name is:

```
FirstName LastName
```

so you need to extract the LastName and use `group by` to get the average:

```
select 
  substr(name, instr(name, ' ') + 1) lastname,
  avg(avg_spending) avg_spending
from customer 
group by lastname
having count(*) > 1
```

The having clause restricts the results to those customer names that have at least 1 other customer name with the same last name.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=efadd49bb27d76f0242bf8ab125bd75d).
For the sample data:

```
> cuid | name      | age | avg_spending
> :--- | :-------- | :-- | :-----------
> 4    | Henk Krom | 65  | 24          
> 9    | Bob Krom  | 66  | 4           
> 5    | Jack Doe  | 66  | 4           
> 7    | Jill Doe  | 66  | 6           
> 1    | Alice No  | 66  | 44
```

you get results:

```
> lastname | avg_spending
> :------- | :-----------
> Doe      | 5           
> Krom     | 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in joining the customer table to itself but you also need to parse out the last name to compare and remove duplicates once a match was found since if nameA equals nameB then nameB has to equal nameA.

```
with custs AS
(
select distinct
    a.name as name_1 , 
    b.name as name_2
from customer a
join customer b
 on substr(a.name, instr(a.name, ' ') + 1) = substr(b.name, instr(b.name, ' ') + 1)  
where a.name like '%Krom%' and a.name <> b.name
)
select * from customer where name in (select name_1 from custs)
union 
select * from customer where name in (select name_2 from custs)
```